# React with babel 7, babel 6 seem to be loading by some other dependency

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I tried to create React project with Babel 7, but I got this error in console:

> Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you
>   are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely
>   that something in your build process is loading the wrong version.
>   Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that
>   doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling
>   Babel. (While processing preset:
>   "/Users/olgababic/fishingbooker/application/assets/js/fbkr-components/packages/recent-search-dash-card/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

I tried to instal @babel/register and babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0 and adding:

```
"resolutions": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0"
}
```

But nothing seemed to help.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "recent-search-dash-card",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "docs"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lib": "babel src/lib -d dist",
    "lib:watch": "babel src/lib -w -d dist",
    "docs": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "docs:prof": "webpack -p"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: how about checking your package-lock.json,find the actual version that you installed.

Comment: @babel/core version is 7.1.2 and all the @babel dependencies are 7 and above (in my package-lock.json)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing @babelc/cli + finding in my package-lock.json which dependency installed version 6+